# angular 5 with angularjs in iframe

Tags: angular, performance, iframe

Hi I build a wrapper with angular 5 that contains side navigation header and iframe as a content .
in the side navigation I'm navigate to a specific URL in app in angularjs or angular 5 (until will finish the migration) and the URL is bind to iframe SRC.
The problem is that in the first time the app in the iframe takes to long to render... Anybody know how to prerender or fetching the apps for better performance?

Comment: Maybe load the iframe ahead of time, but keep it hidden until you need to show it?

Comment: But still when We change route the user need to wait to the other app...you suggests to add  few I frames?

Comment: I meant a single iframe, but load it somewhere else in the DOM while keeping it hidden, then just move the iframe element into the place where you want it once you need it. That should help with the delay for the first time it's loaded. Then once you navigate away, you just move the iframe element back to where you had it before, since your component will be destroyed.